# Sound input in a web page

Tags: html, audio, input

When looking for information about sound in a web page.
All kind of resources come about putting sound for listening.

What I want is a web form where the user can say something and the sound will be recorded and sent over to a server like it can be done with text.

How can this be done?

Comment: This question lacks research... If you want to send it as sound, a simple search for "recording user microphone javascript" would have given you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820578/how-to-capture-audio-in-javascript and if you want it to be sent as text then "speech recognition javascript" would have lead you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition

Comment: Indeed there were things I did not find..... "Mea culpa".
I had not used "javascript" as keyword and that was the BIG MISTAKE.
In other words: if I had known half of the answer I wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a website [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) that explains it, but essentially here's how you capture user audio input:

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: This would work only from mobile devices.